# Yesod: selectField in input form

Tags: forms, yesod

I have an already-existing form built with Bootstrap. This form contains not only `input` items, but `<select>` item as well (it's a list of colours):

```
<form .form-horizontal
      #addEventForm
      role=form
      method=post
      action=@{AddEventAtDateR currentDate}>
    ...
    <label for=diaryEventBackgroundColor
           .col-sm-4
           .control-label>
        _{MsgEventColor}
    <div .col-sm-7>
        <select .form-control #color>
            <option value=grey selected>
                _{MsgBackgroundColorGrey}
            <option value=red>
                _{MsgBackgroundColorRed}
            <option value=orange>
                _{MsgBackgroundColorOrange}
    ...
```

And this is my code:

```
event <- runInputPost $ NewEvent <$> ireq textField         "title"
                                 <*> iopt textareaField     "description"
                                 <*> ireq timeFieldTypeTime "beginTime"
                                 <*> ireq dayField          "beginDate"
                                 <*> ireq (selectField ?)   "color"
```

How can I extract a value from `<select>` item "color"? In all examples (in Yesod Book) I see `selectField` in `AForm`s only.

Comment: What about just using a `textField`, since you don't need Yesod to help with the rendering?

Comment: Is it possible?? Ok, I'll try it. Thank you, Michael.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I use `textField`, and it compiles, but at runtime I get error: `Input not found: color`, where `color` is an id of item. And it's correct: I use `<select>` tag in this case, not the `<input>` tag. So how can I extract `textField` from `<select>` tag?

Comment: I think that's because you didn't set the name attribute.

Comment: Yes, Michael, you're completely right! I forgot `name` attribute. Stupid error, I know... Thank you again!